# Add-Type - Handling functions that have struct parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a function into PowerShell that has a Struct as a parameter.  I'm getting a "type not found" error, but I'm not sure how to include it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
  $MethodDefinition = (
'[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);')

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
```

====EDIT====

So this code does load the function:

```
$MethodDefinition =
@'

public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr BaseAddress;
    public IntPtr AllocationBase;
    public uint AllocationProtect;
    public uint RegionSize;
    public uint State;
    public uint Protect;
    public uint Type;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int     dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);
'@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
```

But I'm getting an error trying to access the function.

Code:

```
$bMem = $Kernel32[1] #the structure, found that $Kernel32 is now an array
[Win32.Kernel32]::VirtualQueryEx($handle, 0, [ref] $bMem, 28);
```

Error:

```
 Method invocation failed because [Win32.Kernel32] doesn't contain a method named 'VirtualQueryEx'.
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your `VirtualQueryEx` does not marked as `public`, so it `private` by default, thus does not visible to PowerShell method resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run this, it tells me that you missing the declaration of [`MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
The type or namespace name 'MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

So try this:

```
$MethodDefinition =
@'

public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr BaseAddress;
            public IntPtr AllocationBase;
            public uint AllocationProtect;
            public uint RegionSize;
            public uint State;
            public uint Protect;
            public uint Type;
        }


[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);
'@


$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
```

Comment: Hi jisaak (and Mathias), your solution worked, but the method doesn't exist.  Can you look at my edits?