# powershell calling exported function of a c++ dll with structure type parameter

Tags: c++, powershell

```
struct foostruct
{
    int B;
    int A;
    int D;
};

int foofunc(foostruct foo)
{
    return foo.A;
}
```

I have exported `FooFunc` from `test.dll` 
Now I am trying to call this from powershell

```
$source =  @"
public struct foostruct {
public int B;
public int A;
public int D;
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -IgnoreWarnings
$bar = New-Object foostruct
$bar.B = 1;
$bar.A = 2;
$bar.D = 3;

$MethodDefinition = @'

[DllImport("test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]

public static extern int foofunc(foostruct foo);

'@

$dll = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'dll' -PassThru -IgnoreWarnings
```

This throws error

`The type or namespace name 'foostruct' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I tried moving the definition of `fostruct` inside `$MethodDefinition` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32218847/3475381) but then when i call it using the below i get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.Object[]'` error.

```
$Result = $dll::foofunc($bar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get `The type or namespace name 'foostruct' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` with your two separate `Add-Type`s is they create separate assemblies under the covers, and the "MemberDefinition" assembly doesn't know about the "TypeDefinition" assembly so can't resolve the `foostruct` type to an implementation.

**Attempt 1 - Failed**

So let's move the two declarations into a single "MemberDefinition" `Add-Type` as per the [answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218847/add-type-handling-functions-that-have-struct-parameters):

```bsh
$source = @"
public struct foostruct
{
    public int B;
    public int A;
    public int D;
}
[DllImport("test\\test\\x64\\Debug\\test.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int foofunc(foostruct foo);
"@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Source -Name "dll";

$bar = New-Object foostruct
$bar.B = 1;
$bar.A = 2;
$bar.D = 3;

$dll::foofunc($bar);
```

Running this works fine for the `Add-Type`, but trying to use `foostruct` gives this error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [foostruct]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\src\so\pinvoke\test.ps1:25 char:8
+ $bar = New-Object foostruct
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

The `foostruct` type is visible to the `DllImport`, but not to PowerShell :-(

**Attempt 2 - Failed**

Ok, let's try it as a "TypeDefinition" `Add-Type` instead:

```bsh
$source = @"
public struct foostruct
{
    public int B;
    public int A;
    public int D;
}
[DllImport("test\\test\\x64\\Debug\\test.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int foofunc(foostruct foo);
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source;

$bar = New-Object foostruct
$bar.B = 1;
$bar.A = 2;
$bar.D = 3;
```

This gives a compile error from `Add-Type` because of the "floating" `[DllImport]` which the compiler is expecting to be wrapped in a class:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\cchnscq4\cchnscq4.0.cs(14) : Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or
struct
c:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\cchnscq4\cchnscq4.0.cs(13) :     [DllImport("test\\test\\x64\\Debug\\test.dll",
CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
c:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\cchnscq4\cchnscq4.0.cs(14) : >>>     public static extern int foofunc(foostruct foo);
c:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\cchnscq4\cchnscq4.0.cs(15) :
At C:\src\so\pinvoke\test.ps1:22 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source;
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

**Attempt 3 - Success**

We can tweak the `$Source` string in the "TypeDefinition" `Add-Type` version above to make the compiler happy:

```bsh
$source =  @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public struct foostruct
{
    public int B;
    public int A;
    public int D;
}

public static class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("test\\test\\x64\\Debug\\test.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int foofunc(foostruct foo);

}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source;

$bar = New-Object foostruct
$bar.B = 1;
$bar.A = 2;
$bar.D = 3;

[NativeMethods]::foofunc($bar);
```

Note that `foofunc` is now a static member of the `[NativeMethods]` class.

The output from *this* version is as follows:

```
2
```

Which is basically the value from `$bar.A` as returned by the C++ function, so everything seems to be working as required.

**Note**

I couldn't reproduce your `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.Object[]'` error so I can't really explain that, but hopefully the answer above helps you solve your problem...